# Is there a way to emulate pinch-zoom?

Tags: firefox, chromium, zooming

I'm looking for a way to emulate pinch zoom in either an android emulator(android SDK-less desirable) or a (preferred) native Ubuntu web browser that I can resize to a specified size for initial testing of HTML5 applications.

This is would be useful for first round testing during cross-platform application development.

Note: I'm trying to do this with no real touch-device only a mouse.  So the **best** answer would be something like "Install this chromium plug-in and use this hotkey to set pinch points" or something similar.

[We already have this](http://ao2.it/en/blog/2010/01/19/poor-mans-multi-touch-using-multiple-mice-xorg) for getting dual mouse working(thanks [AmithKK](https://askubuntu.com/users/17722/amith-kk)).  The browser that supports multi-touch is the hard part.

Something to note is that I start getting screen artifacts using multiple mice via that guide.  They're mild and tolerable, but they are there.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/lock-second-mouse-pointer-keyboard-input-to-one-window don't know if is any use...

Comment: MPWM does look neat, and might help

Comment: I got MPWM to compile, I think, but it does not run on my machine. Are you using compiz?

Comment: @mateo_salta I am using compiz.  I didn't dig through mucking about with MPWM yet, but it definitely looks like a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one for Chromium, I am using E17(enlightenment) for the desktop it will recognize the two mice for moving separate windows at the same time, then using this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/multi%20touch?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Click on the little blue hand near the favorites star, and "try" and use it, Notice that it is terrible, but it's something in the right direction I think.  Trying to preform gestures that you would usually do with fingers is hard.

[image]